# ConsistentHashingPool in Akka - When child of a pool router terminates

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying to implement a ConsistentHashingPool with a fixed amount of routees. However the availability and high throughput are key factors.

This is how I do it at the moment:

```
router = getContext()
            .actorOf(new ConsistentHashingPool(poolSize)
                    .props(Props.create(Worker.class)), 
                    "worker");
```

And my message implements ConsistentHashable. So it should be fine. However I'm wondering how could I replace a terminated child of the router. From what I understood from the documentation once terminated child won't be replaced:

> If the child of a pool router terminates, the pool router will not
>   automatically spawn a new child. In the event that all children of a
>   pool router have terminated the router will terminate itself unless it
>   is a dynamic router, e.g. using a resizer.

Would it fix my problem if I provide a resizer? Am I correct assuming that if a child dies and having a dynamic resizer, the children will be added dynamically, even some of them are terminated?

Cheers