# Get reference of an actor when using a router

Tags: akka, real-time, actor

I am trying to process an event stream which can be "sessionized" into sessions. The plan is to use a pool of actors, where a single actor from the pool would process all events from one session (the reason is I need to maintain some session state). It seems to me that in order for me to achieve this, I would have to keep the ActorRef around for a particular actor which got assigned to a particular session. However, if I am using an actor pool by using:

```
val randomActor = _system.actorOf(Props[SessionProcessorActor].withRouter(RandomPool(100)), name = "RandomPoolActor")
```

Then, in this case, the *randomActor* provides ActorRef to the whole pool, not to the individual actors in the pool. How could I then achieve what I mentioned above?

One way I can think of is to send back the reference after the actor from the pool has been initialized (would probably look something like RandomPoolActor$ab etc.). This method however has a few problems, one of which is I have to use an ask pattern instead of tell, so that I don't miss an event from the same session.

Any other way to achieve this? Any other pattern to adopt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `ConsistentHashingPool` which does something similar to what you are looking for. A `ConsistentHashingRouter` ensures that every message ends in the same actor based on a `hashKey`. This key would be your sessionId in your scenario. There is no need to keep ActorRefs or other references to accomplish this.

There are multiple ways of defining your `hashKey` in your code. I would recommend creating a case class that extends `ConsistentHashable`. Once done you will be required to implement the method `consistentHashKey`. Example:

```
case class HashableEnvelope(yourMsgClass: YourMsgClass) extends ConsistentHashable {
  override def consistentHashKey = yourMsgClass.sessionId
}
```

Then you can define your pool like this:

```
val pool = system.actorOf(Props[SessionProcessorActor].withRouter(ConsistentHashingPool(100)))
```

Another thing to mention is that the router will ensure that all messages with the same hashKey will end up in the same actor, however, it does not ensure that a particular actor receives only messages for a given hashKey. It can receive for multiple hashKeys. That should not be a problem, just your `SessionProcessorActor` should be able to process a few hashKeys instead of just one.

The consistent hashing algorithm will decide which message go to each actor. You can read on wikipedia how it works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing. To distribute messages in a more  evenly manner you should increase the number of virtual nodes in the configuration (default is 10):

```
akka.actor.deployment.default.virtual-nodes-factor = 1000
```

Depending on how many sessionIds and actors you have, you will see that message are getting distributed more evenly.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the comment. Will try this out - might be exactly what I am looking for. One quick question: does this mean the actor for a particular hashcode actually stays alive in memory forever, unless being manually terminated? In that case, it would also mean that if I put some session states in those actors, they will keep occupying memory, isn't it?

Comment: Found a related question in SO here, which is also unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075224/consistenthashingpool-in-akka-when-child-of-a-pool-router-terminates

Comment: The router will route messages based on the hashKey. Messages will end up in the same actor unless that actor is terminated or it dies. If that happens, the route will decide which other actor should be getting messages for that particular hashKey based on the algorithm and start routing them. If you add some state to the routees of the routers, yes that state will occupy memory until the actor terminates or dies. There is nothing wrong in having stateful actors, the problem comes if you need to keep the state when the actor dies. Take a look to Akka persistence for that.

Comment: Accepting as solution - akka persistance would be the way to go.